# Exclude sheets when looping through sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I would appreciate some assistance with the code below. What I'm trying to accomplish is perform some code to each sheet in a workbook except three sheets. My code below goes through every tab but I have not been able to figure out to skip the three sheets.

```
Sub Worksheet_Loop()

Dim ws As Worksheet

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        Debug.Print ws.Name

    End If
  Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an if statement:

```
Sub Worksheet_Loop()

Dim ws As Worksheet

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.name <> "Sheet1" and ws.name <> "Sheet2" And ws.name <> "Sheet3" then
        Debug.Print ws.Name         
    End If
  Next ws

End Sub
```